# Driving relay using attiny48

Tags: pcb-design, relay

I'm making a circuit which contains 6 relais. The circuit is powered by battery (2xAA alkaline in series).

I'm about to submit my fourth iteration for a small test production batch, but the last 3 had issues. (Missing resistors, transistors in BCE instead of BEC configuration, etc...)

I'll be having 6 of these relays on one board.

Will my following circuit work:
[image]

left_steer is an input from the attiny48. For the components I'm planning to use the following:
https://www.digikey.nl/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/CAY16-331J4LF/2566735
https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/microchip-technology/ATTINY48-PU/1886246
https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J1031C3VDC-15S/14001722
https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/BC846A-235/1232258
https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BZX84C3V9TS-7-F/1934545

I'm especialy unsure about the diode arrays. Are those suited to use as flyback diodes?

Comment: Keep your battery chemistry and characteristics in mind. For example NiMH batteries can droop to 1 V, which brings you under the relay's 2.25 V minimum. (Your schematic is also hard to follow: among other things it's unclear if there are missing junction dots at the bottom or what those nets are.)

Comment: Where are your design specs?  Murphy's Law strikes often without these.

Comment: Consider the many inexpensive 6 or 8 channel Relay boards on the web with opto isolation , or is this for Analog Mux signals?

Comment: @TypeIA I updated the schematic screenshot. Is this better? As for the relay, thanks for mentioning it. But I personally don't see a lot of better options. https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/cui-devices/SR1-3V-450-1C/16602073 is slightly better, but also twice as expensive. Do you have hints on how to solve that? I'm planning on using alkaline batteries.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Do you have an example of specifications?

Comment: You don't need zener diodes here, single standard diodes simplify the layout.

Comment: @Jens how do they simplify the layout? The advanttage to me of these is that they come in a SOC363 package with 3 diodes in one. I couldn't find that readily available for standard diodes.

Comment: Any datasheet is an example of detailed specifications. Simple specs may suffice here. Only you know what you have and need

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg I like to have the diodes close to the coils avoiding large noisy loops. It is a kind of EMI paranoia.

Comment: If so, you would be better off with discrete diodes, one near each coil. And a Zener is useless if you still use it like a normal diode.

Comment: I'm looking at https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BAS70DW-06-7-F/751518 now, for placing on the bottom of the PCB close to the relais. Is this better than what I have now?

@Justme do you mean "Zener is no better than normal", or do you mean "Zener doesn't work as a normal"?

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg You talk about Zeners but link to Schottky. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Justme does https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BZX84C3V9TS-7-F/1934545 work (I have those laying around) or do I need to get https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BAS70DW-06-7-F/751518 ? Is there a noticable difference in this application?

Comment: I don't understand why would you even consider a zener because it makes no sense. A 3.9V Zener would already conduct some amount of current when there is 3V over it, and fresh batteries can have around 3.2 volts. Also Schottky diodes have more reverse leakage than standard diodes. Why do you insist putting Zeners or Schottkies there instead of standard diodes?

Comment: @Justme Because I'm a noob, and really starting to notice how much I don't know.

https://www.digikey.nl/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BAV70DW-7-F/775724
This is a "standard" diode, and from what I see this indeed has less reverse current. To me it seems like this would be a suitable candidate. Is this correct?

Comment: I figured I'd hire a freelancer, as it seems I reached the limit of my knowledge.